# Why is faust stream not printing any message?

Tags: python, faust

My faust set up is not printing any messages to console. I originally thought this was an authorization issue, but I've been able retrieve raw messages following the example here ([How to get faust to send raw replies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60341736/how-to-get-faust-to-send-raw-replies)). I want to be able to retrieve the messages using just `await test()`

This is my code...

```
import asyncio
import faust
from faust.types.auth import AuthProtocol

broker_credentials.protocol = AuthProtocol.SASL_SSL

app = faust.App(
    "TOPIC",
    broker=broker,
    value_serializer="json",
    broker_credentials=broker_credentials,
    topic_allow_declare=False, 
    topic_disable_leader=True,
)

test_topic = app.topic(TOPIC)

async def test():
  async for event in app.stream(test_topic):
    print(event)
    
await test()
```

Does anyone have any advice? Right now the loop just seems to hang

Answer (score 0):

A function cannot be awaited like that. A method can be awaited only inside an async function. The await keyword needs to be present inside an async function.
You can follow the [Faust docs](https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for an example.

```
import asyncio
import faust

app = faust.App("sample-agent",broker=broker_url)
test_topic = app.topic("sample-topic")

@app.agent(test_topic)
async def test(stream):
    async for event in stream:
        print(event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.main()
```

After this you can run the script using the following command

```
python script.py worker -l info
```